# Problem with concatenating a variable, result of a cat and cut command

Tags: linux, bash, variables, cut, cat

I have a bash script in which I read a file *`.properties`* and I get a property that I store in a variable:

```
PROP_VALUE=`cat $PROP_FILE | grep "^$PROP_KEY" | cut -f2 -d'='`
```

This variable is set to **5.0.1**.

When I want to use this variable and concatenate it to a second variable, I get the following result:

```
CONCAT=".0"
echo $PROP_VALUE
=> Result : 5.0.1

echo $PROP_VALUE$CONCAT
=> Result : .00.1
```

This removes the first 2 characters of my first variable (`$ PROP_VALUE`) and replaces them with the characters of my second variable (`$ CONCAT`).

The expected result is: **5.0.1.0**

Comment: working fine for me. Giving the expected result. `echo $PROP_VALUE$CONCAT
5.0.1.0`. Could you show us the PROP_FILE once? Maybe something wrong while fetching PROP_VALUE.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your result. BTW, you should use `$(...)` syntax for command substitution over the deprecated backticks form.

Comment: @danlor Who says it's deprecated? It's still a part of standard

Comment: @oguzismail Well, it depends on what you understand by deprecated, maybe it is a little misleading here. Anyway, you can check out https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126927/have-backticks-i-e-cmd-in-sh-shells-been-deprecated to clarify.

Comment: @danlor oh, okay. thanks for clarifying it

Comment: BTW, no need to torture a `cat` for this.

Answer (score 3):

Ensure that your .properties is a real unix file. If it is, then your script is ok. If .properties has DOS/winslows encoding, then you are in trouble. There is no other explanation, I think.

Comment: I think the problem comes from there ... but I can not "convert" the file to the risk that it does not "work" anymore with a windows environment ...

Comment: @Ludo06 interoperability shouldn't be an issue unless this properties file was programmatically generated using some strange encoding.  Use `file file.properties` and see what it's encoding is.  Converting it to UTF8 shouldn't be an issue, or use the tool `dos2unix` ... files converted with that open perfectly fine in Windows

Comment: You can repair with (untested) `PROP_VALUE=${PROP_VALUE%$'\r'}` (Bash-specific) - there's no need to edit the input file.

Comment: Comment above is promising. Or, you could pipe the output of dos2unix: cat | dos2unix | grep. I don't have a system to try, so it is just an untested idea.

Answer (score 0):

My property file :

```
version=5.0.1
category=dev
env=rct
```

When I use the following syntax I have the same problem :

```
PROP_VALUE=$(cat $PROP_FILE | grep "^$PROP_KEY" | cut -f2 -d'=')
```

If $PROP_VALUE is a variable that I created manually (without going to retrieve the value in my property file), it works :

```
PROP_VALUE="5.0.1"
CONCAT=".0"
echo $PROP_VALUE$CONCAT
=> Result : 5.0.1.0
```

Comment: what is value of PROP_KEY here?

Comment: The value of PROP_KEY is "version"

Comment: It still works for me. The command substitution syntax thing was only a recommendation, aside from the problem itself.

Comment: @Ludo06 what do you get when you type `cat "$PROP_FILE"`

Comment: @hmedia1 I get the contents of my properties file... 
with the command grep I get the key of the property and with the command cut I get the value of the property ...

Comment: @Ludo06 copy and paste this entire one-liner and describe the output: `echo -e 'version=5.0.1\ncategory=dev\nenv=rct' > file.properties ; PROP_FILE=file.properties ; PROP_KEY=version ; CONCAT=".0" ; PROP_VALUE="$(cat $PROP_FILE | grep "^$PROP_KEY" | cut -f2 -d'=')" ; echo $PROP_VALUE$CONCAT`